# Html table design issues with row data

Tags: html, html-table

I am facing issues with designing this table below as per image:
[image]

I tried below table basic html table tr > td structure but nothing is helping me to get desired output.

Comment: Show us the code you tried please

Comment: <table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Estimated Time</td>
    <td>Value</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Delivery Charge</td>
    <td>Value</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Value</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Payment Method</td>
    <td>Value</td>
  </tr>
</table>

Comment: take a look here https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_table_span

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `rowspan` attribute like so:

```css
#table1 {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
#table1 td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table id="table1">
  <tr>
    <td>Estimated Time</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">Delivery Charge</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Payment Method</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```